# Read JSON data one by one in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have written a JSON file using TypeScript/TestCafe.

```
import fs = require("fs");

fixture`Create test data and pass them to the other tests`
  .page(url)
  .before(async (t) => {
    await createData();
  });

// Write data into a JSON file
async function createData() {
  var fname = 'Amanda';
  var lname = 'Hiddleston';
  let guardian = {
    firstName: fname,
    lastName: lname,
  };
  let data = JSON.stringify(guardian);
  fs.writeFileSync("data.json", data);
}
```

And want to read firstName and LastName separately. For that, I used this method:

```
interface MyObj {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

var data = require("./data.json");
let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(data);

test("Read first name from the JSON file", async (t) => {
  console.log(obj.firstName); // print first name
});

test("Read last name from the JSON file", async (t) => {
  console.log(obj.lastName); // print last name
});
```

But it shows an error in the line `let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(data)`.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Custom type guards are the simplest solution and often sufficient for external data validation:

```
// For example, you expect to parse a given value with `MyType` shape
type MyType = { name: string; description: string; }

// Validate this value with a custom type guard
function isMyType(o: any): o is MyType {
  return "name" in o && "description" in o
```

Comment: When calling the isMyType method, you are supposed to pass some values right? But I need to read data from the JSON file.